Where to find the modelURN of a model in Autodesk Tandem Web UI?
Where can I find the modelURN of any model in my facility in Autodesk Tandem?
I am using the web UI.
I tried searching the entire platform for an option to check the modelURN associated with a conference room chair model I added in my Test Facility but couldn’t find one anywhere.
Does the modelURN correspond to an Asset or a Facility?

Currently there isn't way to get URN of the model directly in the UI, but you can use following steps to get model URN of specific element:

Open browser console
Select element
In the console enter:

NOP_VIEWER.getAggregateSelection()[0].model.myData.modelUrn

This will print out model URN to console, i.e.:
urn:adsk.dtm:2e_Tvt8pSfqGhQeBVn8lsg

The model URN represents individual model of the facility. Facility can have multiple models. One model can contain multiple assets.
If you need to get model URNs for multiple elements you can use Inventory -> Export - the value is stored under DtModelId column.
